# How to reduce docker image size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerhub

I'm using docker official rails onbuild pack (https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rails/) to build and create rails image with application. But each application is taking about 900MB. Is there any way this size can be reduced?

Here's my workflow ->

```
add dockerfile to the project -> build -> run
```

The problem is there can be N number of apps on this system and if each application takes 1G of disk space it would be an issue. If we reduce layers will it reduce size? If yes how can that be done?

```
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              VIRTUAL SIZE
blog2                latest              9d37aaaa3beb        About a minute ago   931.1 MB
my-rails-app         latest              9904zzzzc2af        About an hour ago    931.1 MB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they are all coming from the same base image, they don't each take 900MB (assuming you're using AUFS as your file system*). There will be one copy of the base image (`_/rails`) and then the changes you've made will be stored in separate (usually much smaller) layers.

If you would like to see the size of each image layer, you might like to play with [this tool](https://github.com/samalba/docker-registry-debug). I've also containerized it [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/rufus/docker-registry-debug/).

*) If you're using `docker` on Ubuntu or Debian, you're probably defaulting to AUFS. Other host Linux versions can use different file systems for the images, and they don't all share base images well.